# Create a dvar boolean Constraint

Tags: binary, constraints, cplex, opl

I am using OPL CPLEX 12.9

I have problems with the formulation of the following constraint:

- K[i][t] is a dvar boolean and t is the Index for time.
- If K[i][t] == 0 it should be zero for two hours, before it goes 1 again.

I would like to achieve for example the following result

```
K[i][t] = [0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ]
```

I already tried:

```
range T = t_min..t_max;

range T1 = t_min-1 ..t_max+1;

dvar boolean K[I][T1];

forall ( i in I, t in T){ 

ct:

(K[i][t-1]==0) => (K[i][t]== 0) => (K[i][t+1]==1 || K[i][t+1]==0) &&

(K[i][t-1]==1) => (K[i][t]==1 || K[i][t]==0);
```

But in the results, these side conditions are ignored. I get the result like

```
K[i][t] = [0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 ]
```

Comment: A few days ago I answered the same question in Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087318/how-to-force-succesive-variable-to-be-of-same-value/58093604?r=SearchResults#58093604

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your condition reads "if K[i][t] is 0 then either K[i][t-1] or K[i][t+1] must be zero as well". So you need

```
forall (i in ...) {
  (K[i][t_min] == 0) => (K[i][t_min+1] == 0);
  (K[i][t_max] == 0) => (K[i][t_max-1] == 0);
  forall(t in t_min+1..t_max-1)
    (K[i][t] == 0) => ((K[i][t-1] == 0) || (K[i][t+1] == 0));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help guys! It solves my problem, I am really happy now!